# how Manim execute a package project?

Tags: python, module, configuration, python-module, manim

I am currently working with manim, I have structured my project in the form of a package
[Directory where the project is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i3GR.png)
when trying to run any file I usually do it with
the command

```bash
python -m animations.example
```

This from a directory outside of animations, the question is that when trying
run the file with manim

```bash
manim -p animations\example.py Escena
```

It throws an error as to why in the code of `example.py` I use variables
from the other modules of the package:

```py
from manim import *
from components.backgrounds import *


class Escena(MovingCameraScene):
    def construct(self):
        #change background
        self.camera.background = black

        message = Text("Hello world")
        self.play(Write(message))
        self.play(Wiggle(message), run_time=3)
        self.play(Unwrite(message))
```

I think this is because when using the `manim` command it doesn't recognize the imported modules
and used, then try using a command something like the first:

```bash
manim -p animations.example.Escena
```

But it doesn't work either, I think this is due to a correct use of the modules, but
I don't know how to solve this mishap help!

```bash
manim -p animations.example.Escena
```

Then the Scene is rendered and shows the video, but that didn't happen